# Multiple != versus == operators

Tags: python-3.6, comparison-operators

The following program works exactly as expected:

```
data = input("Input the length of three sides of a triangle: ").strip()

if data.count(',') != 2:
    print("You did not enter the lengths of three sides: ")

a, b, c = data.split(', ')


def triangle_type(s1, s2, s3):
    if s1 == s2 == s3:
        return print("The values entered represent an equilateral triangle.")
    elif s1 != s2 and s1 != s3 and s2 != s3:
        return print("The values entered represent a scalene triangle.")
    else:
        if s1 == s2 or s1 == s3 or s2 == s3:
            return print("The values entered represent an isosceles triangle.")


triangle_type(int(a), int(b), int(c))
```

However, if I change the second condition to the following:

```
elif s1 != s2 != s3:
```

it does NOT work as expected.

If I input 3, 6, 3 I get:

```
Input the length of three sides of a triangle: 3, 6, 3
The values entered represent a scalene triangle.
```

This is incorrect.  This should clearly match condition #3 (isosceles).

It works correctly with the first version of the code.

I am confused on two things:

1)  Why does the second version work improperly?

2)  If the second version is invalid, then why does the first condition work
correctly?

Given the above behavior with the !=  operator, I would expect to have to treat a == b == c like a == b and a == c and b == c, but I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chain comparisons in Python, it `and`s them together, and it only does as many comparisons as you have comparison operators. So

```
if s1 == s2 == s3:
```

is equivalent to

```
if s1 == s2 and s2 == s3:
```

That works because if both of those conditions are `True`, then `s1` *must* also be equal to `s3` (because they're both equal to `s2`).

However

```
if s1 != s2 != s3:
```

is equivalent to

```
if s1 != s2 and s2 != s3:
```

As you've discovered, for the values 3, 6, and 3, the above two conditions are `True`, but the third assumed condition (`s1 != s3`) is not `True`. This doesn't work as you expect because Python isn't making that third comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The chained version is equivalent to `s1 != s2 and s2 != s3`; it does not require that `s1 != s3`, because inequality is not transitive.